# How to change the color environment tasks in latex?

Tags: color, tasks

[image]

```
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task {\color{red}
$3x^3 - 21x$}
\task {\color{red}
$5x^6 + 15x^4$}
\task {\color{red}
$4x^3 + 10x^2 - 2x$}
\end{tasks}
```

How to change the color number tasks. Please, help!

Answer (score 4):

I assume that just the math material should be in red. If that's the case, the following code will achieve your formatting-related objective.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tasks}{\everymath{\color{red}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task  $3x^3 - 21x$
\task  $5x^6 + 15x^4$
\task  $4x^3 + 10x^2 - 2x$
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Aside: Issue the instruction `\settasks{style=enumerate}` after loading the `tasks` package to get the tasks enumerated with arabic numerals followed by a period ("full stop").

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the whole task in red, you need a small patch of an internal expl3 code as it currently resets everything to black:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{style=enumerate}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter
%patch needed to get a around a problem in the l3-drivers
\AtBeginDocument{
 \cs_set_protected_nopar:Npn \color_ensure_current:
   {\set@color}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother 

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\color{red}
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task $3x^3 - 21x$
\task 
$5x^6 + 15x^4$
\task $4x^3 + 10x^2 - 2x$
\end{tasks}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set both the `item-format` *and* the `label-format`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks,color}

\settasks{
  style = enumerate ,
  label-format = \bfseries
}

\begin{document}

% local:
In exercises 1--8, factor the common factor in the polynomials.
\begin{tasks}[label-format=\color{red}\bfseries,item-format=\color{red}](3)
  \task  $3x^3 - 21x$
  \task  $5x^6 + 15x^4$
  \task  $4x^3 + 10x^2 - 2x$
\end{tasks}

% for all lists:
\settasks{
  label-format = \color{red}\bfseries ,
  item-format  = \color{red}
}

In exercises 1--8, factor the common factor in the polynomials.
\begin{tasks}(3)
  \task  $3x^3 - 21x$
  \task  $5x^6 + 15x^4$
  \task  $4x^3 + 10x^2 - 2x$
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]